How to stop UPnP broadcasts for USB device insert / remove
When I insert / remove a USB flash drive in a fresh Xubuntu 24.04 minimal install + docker + VirtualBox + ufw enabled, I see these messages in dmesg:
[ 5787.637031] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Fit       1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 5787.637634] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 5787.644543] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[ 5787.645860] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 5787.645871] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 5787.646232] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 5787.663282]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[ 5787.663652] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5788.013976] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 5788.015295] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 5788.016440] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
[ 5788.249260] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC= SRC=169.254.113.42 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=1213 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=33066 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[ 5788.249518] [UFW BLOCK] IN=docker0 OUT= MAC= SRC=172.23.113.14 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=38685 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39500 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[ 5788.249565] [UFW BLOCK] IN=vboxnet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=45631 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=55391 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[ 5845.646843] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 5846.174007] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC= SRC=169.254.113.42 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=38967 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35183 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[ 5846.174303] [UFW BLOCK] IN=docker0 OUT= MAC= SRC=172.23.113.14 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=51450 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39960 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[ 5846.174346] [UFW BLOCK] IN=vboxnet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=635 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=33715 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54053 DPT=3702 LEN=615

If I'm reading those messages correctly, it appears that a UPnP service of some kind is spamming broadcast UDP messages to 239.255.255.250:3702 on all my active network interfaces.  ufw is blocking the traffic (as desired) but... how do I stop it from being sent in the first place?
I'd really rather not broadcast-advertise to every network interface I'm connected to every time I plug / unplug a memory stick.
Already tried: killing thunar -daemon
No change. thunar not running at all, but the UPnP messages are still happening.
Related? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery  Could these be coming from the avahi-daemon?  I tried pkilling it, but it comes right back, I guess I would have to find the systemd service...

The mystery broadcast packets do seem to be coming from avahi-daemon, and mucking around in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf I do seem to be able to influence what it produces, block interfaces it has no business on, and stop some broadcasts, though I am still getting a fair bit of IP6 traffic even though I set use-ipv6=no ...
I do want to be able to recognize network printers when they broadcast themselves, but otherwise I'd like my system to remain "dark."  Any good guides out there for configuring avahi-daemon?
Thanks,
